# Does copying something from SysWOW64 need admin priveleges

Tags: windows, admin, privileges

So I have made a program which copies some files from `System32` on `32 bit` machine while `SYSWOW64` on 64 bit machine to another destination after the User accepts it. I have added an `administrator manifest` in it so it asks for admin privileges before starting. Is that necessary? I don't want to cook the Users brain by asking him every time for admin privileges. So does copying something from the above two locations need admin privileges?

Regards,

Comment: Yes, you cannot monkey with these operating system directories without asking for permission.  Cooking is required, especially given what you are doing is so dangerous.  Convincing the user that clicking OK is okay and won't screw up his machine is your job.  Given that you had to ask, I'd always click Cancel.

Comment: Copying *from* the SysWOW64 folder does not require admin privilege.  Admin privilege may be required for the copy depending on where you are copying *to*.

Comment: @HansPassant They already know about the risks and are doing it on their own. You were to click cancel then you wouldn't have installed the program in the first place. I like to keep my users happy and tricking them into something isn't what I like to do. They already know what alll risks will be there as It was already told to them before they installed the program and also in the terms and conditions

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ok thanks, exactly the answer I was wondering, post that as an answer and I will green check it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Reading files does not require admin permission, though writing does.

There are a number of implications of this:

1. If you install Apache, you can read the httpd.conf with notepad but saving fails unless you disable UAC.
2. You can copy a file from a system directory, but you cannot save a file to a system directory without asking via UAC.

BTW this is one of my biggest issues with UAC -- it means that things behave strangely and that writes can fail after you have already made changes, which can be very annoying if you come from a UNIX background and expect it to work something like `sudo`....